# Wrong colorAccent when retrieving from theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles

I want to use colorAccent from application theme. There are two themes with different accent colors. I am implement it with this code:

Styles:

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppGreenTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
</style>

<style name="AppRedTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/receives_funds_share"
    android:background="?colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

But it shows wrong color (#04dac6). When the correct color is darker (#05c0a5).

When I changed it from `android:background="?colorAccent"` to android:background="@color/green" it works well. What it the difference? How to correctly retrieve accentColor from style?

Tested on Android 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, since you are using `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` as your parent, `colorAccent` does not apply. Instead try replacing it with `colorSecondary` as follows.

The `Theme.MaterialComponents` uses the `colorSecondary` and is so described in their docs. All the components defined in the library uses this attribute.

```xml
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppGreenTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/green</item>
</style>

<style name="AppRedTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I've tried to change view's background to ?colorSecondary and replace it styles. But no result.

Comment: @BArtWell Okay, this might be a long shot, but can you check if there is no override for styles like `v21` or something like that. I have had that happen.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just add it to v27 styles and now it works correctly. It is strange that was showing very simular color before. Thank you!

Comment: @BArtWell That is indeed infuriating, but it has happened to me before. So your `v27` was overriding what you were doing here and thus it was not working. Well, glad it is figured out now.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the theme to the activity in `mainfest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppGreenTheme">
</activity>
```

Comment: Yes. I've also tried to set theme programmatically and set it both to Application and Activity tags. But no success, color is still wrong.